# Trying to create empty asset collection using "com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.collection.DamCollectionManager;"

Tags: assets, aem-6, dam

Trying to create empty asset collection using "com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.collection.DamCollectionManager;" but import is failing for this. Added required dependency as well for "cq-dam-core"

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.day.cq.dam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cq-dam-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.14</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

While trying to using this as a service the OSGI annotation @reference is not of help as well.

Any help would be helpful.